Databricks Autoloader batch mode
I am seeking guidance on handling full load scenarios within Databricks using Autoloader. Please don't go too hard on me, since I lack practical experience at this point in time.
My scenario is a system that makes daily full extracts. Each day it dumbs all its files to a particular location: mnt/landing/. The folder can be cleaned afterwards, ensuring autoloader looks for new files.
I want to use this files to update (overwrite) my bronze layer. During this process I would like to validate the schema. For this, I'm first fetching my current schema. Note the code below fetches data from the landing zone. It's a bit more dynamic. If the data is loaded already, I would like to fetch the schema from my bronze layer.
schema_json = spark.read.parquet("/mnt/landing/20240826/SalesLT.Address.parquet").schema.json()
ddl = spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.fromJson(schema_json).toDDL()
print(ddl)

Next, I'm reading and writing all data using Autoloader. I use the schema as input. Again, if there's no data yet, I'm using the schema from the landing zone, ensuring data can be loaded properly.
(spark.readStream
 .format("cloudFiles")
 .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
 .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "/mnt/landing/_checkpoint/address_autoload/")
 .schema(ddl)
 .load("/mnt/landing/SalesLT.Address.parquet")
 .writeStream
 .format("delta")
 .outputMode("append")
 .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/landing/_checkpoint/address_autoload/")
 .trigger(once = True)
 .option("mode", "overwrite")
 .toTable("adventureworks.address"))

However, when I check my destination. The data is empty.
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM adventureworks.address")
display(df)

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Instead of determining the schema before, can you try using mergeSchema?
(spark.readStream
 .format("cloudFiles")
 .option("cloudFiles.format", "parquet")
 .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "/mnt/landing/_checkpoint/address_autoload/")
 .load("/mnt/landing/SalesLT.Address.parquet")
 .writeStream
 .format("delta")
 .outputMode("append")
 .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/landing/_checkpoint/address_autoload/")
 .option("mergeSchema", "true")  # Enable schema evolution
 .trigger(once=True)
 .option("mode", "overwrite")
 .toTable("adventureworks.address"))


You might be missing waiting for the query to finish. Do you have .awaitTermination() on the end?
